# Why doesn't 'in' works for checking if a specific word is in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, basically I'm working with string manipulation for a chatbot. When it returns a string from a message, I'm just checking if there's an specific word on it:

```
let msg = 'how are you?'                     //Message example
let words = msg.split(' ')                   //Words spliting
if ('are' in words) {}                       //This is where I'm having the problem
```

I know that `in` works for when I check a number inside of an array, but it doesn't seem to work with strings. Is there a different way to call it when it's about strings? I could do the checking using a loop, then a `if (words[i] === 'are') {}`, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: Please read the documentation on [the `in` operator](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Comment: Because strings can be keys (property names) of objects, and that is the purpose of the `in` operator.

Comment: *"I know that `in` works for when I check a number inside of an array"* It doesn't. `in` operator checks if the object has the given key. You are probably doing something like `if(1 in [1,2,3])`. It returns true because the array has the key `1`. If you do `if (1 in [2,3,4])`, that ALSO returns true because it doesn't check the value, but the keys of the array.

Comment: allright, thanks for the explaining

Answer (score 1):

You can use includes:

```
if(words.includes('are')) { }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 1):

You can use `words.includes("are")`. Check the live demo:

```js
let msg = 'how are you?'                     //Message example
let words = msg.split(' ')                   //Words spliting
console.log(words);
if (words.includes("are")) {
   console.log('exist');
} else {
   console.log('not exist');
}
```